# Any normal third degree extension of $\mathbb Q$ contained in $\mathbb C$ must be contained in $\mathbb R$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, galois-extensions, cyclotomic-polynomials, cyclotomic-fields

We let $K\subset \mathbb C$ be a finite normal field extension of $\mathbb Q$ such that $[K:\mathbb Q]=3$. Show that $K\subset \mathbb R$.

I know that no cyclotomic extension of $\mathbb Q$ will do the job, as it will have degree $\varphi(n)$ over $\mathbb Q$, which is never $3$. However, how do I prove that this holds for arbitrary normal field extensions?

Comment: If the degree is three, we have an irreducible polynomial of degree $3$ over $\Bbb Q$. If it has not three real roots, then extension cannot be normal. Compare with the posts here treating the case of $X^3-2$, where the splitting field has degree $6$, and not $3$ - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4623125/why-isn-t-mathbbqx-langle-x3-2-rangle-a-normal-extension-over-mathbb), for example, asked $2$ days ago.

Comment: If $K$ isn't contained in $\mathbb{R}$ then by normality complex conjugation acts on it, which means...?